# How to load Multiple headers into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

there and thank you for spending your time on my question!
I'm using python 3.7 + pandas to load .xlsx file with multiple columns into a dataframe.

My Input:https://i.stack.imgur.com/avzeE.jpg . 
Desired Output (example for the first row only):https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdW3M.jpg

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[2,3,4])
print(df.columns)
```

It returns 'Unnamed 1', 'Unnamed 2' etc as main level header is merged.

I'd appreciate any help.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the index column for this particular excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)
```